# How to separate a dataframe column by intervals, and plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, histogram

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     Edades
0        -15.612896
1        -18.612896
2         11.387104
3        -12.612896
4         17.387104
            ...
566597    15.387104
566598     5.387104
566599     6.387104
566600     0.387104
566601    22.387104
```

I want to make a barplot that shows frequency of the data classified on intervals that are defined by multiples of the standard deviation. So far, I know that `plt.hist()` can actually do something like that but it wont let me use a float type value on the range.

The code I tried is the following:

```
plt.figure("Edad_Distrib")
plt.hist(nuevo_edad, range(-100,100))
plt.xlabel("Edades")
plt.ylabel("Frecuencia")
plt.title("Distrib edades")
plt.show()
```

How can i plot something in a range that looks like this?

```
plt.hist(nuevo_edad, range(-2*stdev,2*stdev))
```

If it serves any purpose, i have this code that my professor did in R that does exactly that with a randomly generated dataframe, i just dont know how to implement it in python and with my specific dataframe.

```
A <- rnorm(100)
m <- mean(A)
s <- var(A)
k <- -11

x = seq(-5, 5, length = k)
y = vector("numeric", length = (k-1))

for (i in 1:(k-1)){
       y[i] = sum(A>x[i] & A<x[i+1])

}

barplot(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Define the bin edges, with `df.a.mean() ± df.a.std() * value`

  - The list-comprehension in the following code, creates a list of bin edges.
- Get the mean of the dataframe with [`pandas.Series.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html)
- Get the standard deviation of the mean with [`pandas.Series.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.std.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  # for sample data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create sample dataframe
np.random.seed(365)
data = {'a': [np.random.randint(700) for _ in range(3000)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create the bin edges
bins = [df.a.mean() + (df.a.std() * v) for v in range(-5, 6, 1)]

print(bins)
[-652.44, -451.49, -250.55, -49.6, 151.35, 352.3, 553.25, 754.19, 955.14, 1156.09, 1357.04]
```

- To manually bin the dataframe, [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the bins, and generate a bar plot

  - [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)
- Use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to create a new column with bins.

```py
# create a column of bins
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df.a, bins=bins)

# groupby the bins and plot
df.groupby('bins')['a'].count().plot.bar()
```

[image]

- Plot a histogram by defining the bin edges, using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html) or [matplotlib.pyplot.hist](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)
- [matplotlib: Histograms](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/statistics/hist.html)

```py
# matplotlib plot
plt.hist(x=df.a, bins=bins)
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()

# or dataframe plot
df.a.plot.hist(bins=bins)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

This was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @MHernandez22 You're welcome. I'm glad this helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a range you most pass it to the function as a [*keyword argument*](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-argument) (`kwarg`), in this case `range`. It will be something like this:

```py
plt.hist(nuevo_edad, range=(-2*stdev,2*stdev))
```

Note that you don't pass a collection (as `range(a, b)`) the argument `range` in `hist` is a tuple of two elements.

PS: this only affects what data you want to plot. If instead of that you mean how many bars you want in the histogram use the param `bins`.

Example:

```py
plt.hist(nuevo_edad, bins=20, range=(-2*stdev,2*stdev))
```

This will plot all the data between `-2*stdev` and `2*stdev` distributed in 20 bars.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it too.